# Create own numpad with inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching the web for some tips regarding how to make your own numpad, created with html code, to act as a numpad would on the computer.

I have this numpad on my website that would give an input to a textfield in the same div. I've given a value to each button and now I guess I would have to create something more so that the numbers will add to my text field.

I'm really a beginner with programming so maybe this is really easy. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to be more specific about the question - tell us what isn't working, give us the code.

Comment: he's asking for exactly that, hes new to web technologies and is looking for links / advice / sample code of what to do and where to go

Comment: have you tried to search anything on google for same.

Comment: if you have used my answer or any of the others please remember to up vote and mark as top answer so others facing the same issue will know which helped you. if not please add comments to answers asking more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it, alternatively, with jQuery. jQuery is better IMHO if you need a simple easy solution (jQuery is generally easier and faster).

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"> </div> //the div to which we add text

<div id="buttonContainer">           //this is the div containing the numbers (the numpad)
<button value="one"> one </button>
<button value="two"> two </button> 
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#buttonContainer button").click(function() {
   $("#myDiv").append($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DLzUU/1/

What this does is: when you click any button inside the div with id of 'buttonContainer', it adds its value to the div with the id of "myDiv".

On the Javascript subject, if you want a VERY good guide: http://javascript.info/

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to learn javascript. With javascript you will be able to write code to do this.

```
<script>

   function AddValueToTextField(val)
   {
      document.getElementByID( <textfiled ID> ).value += val;
   }

</script>

<button onClick="AddValueToTextField(this.value)"></button>
```

this is only very basic but it is a rough idea of what is needed, the button is set to call the function "AddValueToTextField" when it is clicked. When the function is called the value of the button is sent along with it. Inside the function it gets a handle on the textfield and adds the value of the button to whatever was already there, I'd suggest looking at:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/

as a place to start learning javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html[keypad example](http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html), this is an awesome example

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var selected;
$(".admin_loginid input").focus(function(){
    selected = $(this);
});

$(".loginbtn").click(function(){
    selected.val(selected.val() + $(this).val());
});

});
```

Solved it that way and it works really well, thanks for the help! Now my selected input box takes the input from the numpad that i've created.